# Unit test for restTemplate.postForEntity causes ResourceAccessException

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, url, resttemplate

I made a method that just checks if a url that we have running on a port is working.

```
public boolean isBackendRunning() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<Object> entity = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);

    //ResponseEntity<String> out = restTemplate.postForEntity(new URI("https://localhost:8443"), entity, String.class);
    ResponseEntity<String> response
            = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://localhost:8443", String.class);

    return true;

  }
```

The issue is when running our unit test I am always getting `org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException Caused by: java.net.ConnectException`

```
public static MockWebServer mockBackEnd;
      @Autowired Controller Controller;
      MissionController mc = Mockito.mock(Controller.class);
    
      @Mock
      RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
    
      @Mock public ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;

      @Test
  public void GetRequestTest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.getForEntity(any(), eq(String.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
    Mockito.when(mock.isBackendRunning()).thenReturn(true);
    mockBackEnd.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody(response).addHeader(content, app_json));
    assertEquals(
        ...
            .getMissionJSON(MockOAuth2AuthenticationToken.createAuthCountry())
            .toString());
  }
```

In the code sample above I have tried mocking the get restTemplate to just return a result, and mocking the method. I thought that this would prevent the method from actually running the code and just get me a result so we can do the unit test. This is not the case.

How do I handle this check without getting these errors? OpenConnection will not work with how we have a program set up. I have tried so many different ways to get this working with restTemplate.

Comment: What's the rest of the exception?  Is there an inner exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a MissionController class with a RestTemplate dependency, and you want to inject a mock of that dependency into a MissionController instance to unit test the isBackendRunning method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MissionControllerTest {
  @Mock
  private RestTemplate mockRestTemplate;
  @Mock 
  private ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity;
  @InjectMocks
  private MissionController missionController = new MissionController();
  @Test
  public void GetRequestTest() throws Exception {
   Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.getForEntity(any(), 
      any(Class.class))).thenReturn(responseEntity);
   boolean running = missionController.isBackendRunning();

   assertTrue(running);
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get a connectException whenever I call the method isBackendRunning(). Even when adding the Mockito.when. I don't understand why its still looking for a connection if it is being mocked.

Comment: I think I solved it by doing a try catch in the method catching the ResourceAccessException. It works if I do that but I do not understand why I need to catch the exception for a mock.

Comment: I would guess that something in the construction or initialization of MissionController is attempting a connection through some other facility that you would need to mock as well.